# Setting HTML content with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to echo a clock inside a `<div id="details">`, and the script for doing the same at title is like this:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Showing time at title</title>
<script language="javascript">
function showTimes(){
 myDate= new Date()
 realTimes= "Time now " + myDate.getHours() + " : "
 realTimes= realTimes + myDate.getMinutes() + " : "
 realTimes= realTimes + myDate.getSeconds() + "."
 realTimes= realTimes + myDate.getMilliseconds()
 document.title=realTimes
 setTimeout("showTimes()",100)
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="showTimes()">
<img src="img/s8.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

how shall I rewrite the script?? Thanksalot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```
document.title=realTimes`
```

with

```
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML=realTimes
```

would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set `document.getElementById('details').innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
document.title=realTimes
```

with

```
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=realTimes
```